# How to animate TextViews sequentially in Android?

Tags: android, animation, textview, handler

I am developing a question game with four possible answers. Every answer is a TextView. What I want is that after the user selects an answer, and before show the next question, the text boxes associated with the answers leave the screen with an animation to the right but in a sequentially way with a small delay. Below an example of how it would be:

```
                            ---------
                          | Answer 1 |
                           ----------
                  ---------
                | Answer 2 |
                 ----------
         ----------
        | Answer 3 |
         ----------
```

To schedule the start of the animation of each answer view, after a certain delay, I use the Handler class. The problem is that when run the code, the views leave of the screen not sequentially with a delay, they leave of the screen at the same time and I do not get the desired effect.. Obviously I've tried increasing the delay but it does not solve the problem. Here a snippet of the code I use:

```
        TextView answerViewA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswerA);
        TextView answerViewB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswerB);
        TextView answerViewC = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswerC);
        TextView answerViewD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswerD);

        ArrayList<TextView> answerViewCollection = new ArrayList<TextView>(
                4);
        answerViewCollection.add(answerViewA);
        answerViewCollection.add(answerViewB);
        answerViewCollection.add(answerViewC);
        answerViewCollection.add(answerViewD);

        final Animation exitAnim = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(
                mContext, true);
        final int delay = 200;

        for (int i = 0; i < answerViewCollection.size(); i++) {

            final View auxView = answerViewCollection.get(i);

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    auxView.startAnimation(exitAnim);
                }

            }, delay * i);
        }
```

My restriction is: `android:minSdkVersion="10"` . I appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: Have you tried crating an `AnimationSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are reusing the same `Animation` instance to animate different views.

An `Animation` object is not just an animation description, it is a live animation, holding its own animating state. As a result if you share the same `Animation` instance, you share the same animating state, hence the same transformation at a given time.

If your `minSdkVersion` is `10`, I think the right way to go is to use an [`AnimationLayoutController`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html) which is specifically designed to

> (...) animate a layout's, or a view group's, children. Each child uses the same animation but for every one of them, the animation starts at a different time.

You could also create many `Animation` instances with different delays but I'm not sure it would be optimal.

Comment: Hi @ovmjm. Before reading your reply I had already found the solution. Definitely, such as you have written, the solution is to create independent animation for each view. Anyway I want to thank you for your quick and accurate response. However, the alternative you propose through AnimationLayoutController class is definitely the right way to do it. Thank you very much for the tip: D

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answerViewCollection.size(); i++) {
    final View auxView = answerViewCollection.get(i);

    final Animation exitAnim = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this,
            true);
    exitAnim.setDuration(1000);
    exitAnim.setStartOffset(delay * i);
    auxView.startAnimation(exitAnim);
    auxView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Good solution. And no need to use the Handler class. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would better go with the `AnimationLayoutController` which prevents from creating and managing many `Animation` instances and is specifically designed to animate `ViewGroup`'s children. However, if not applicable, @minipif solution _works_.